# Packaging Tesseract 5 with VCPKG

Tags: ocr, tesseract, vcpkg

I'm following the instructions at https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#windows and when I run: vcpkg install tesseract:x86-windows-static It is pulling down tesseract 4. I tried using -head and it still pulls down 4. Any idea how I can build a self-contained executable for tesseract 5.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment vcpkg support version 4.1.1: https://vcpkg.info/port/tesseract

There is request for update: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/16019 from Feb 3, 2021 which Microsoft ignores ;-)

You can (manually) upgrade tesseract version in vcpkg. See tesseract forum discussion: https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/2xAJaGRqymw?pli=1